# Jquery UI draggable revert to the initial position when axis is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, draggable, axis

I want to write code x-axis dragging with shiftkey click, y-axis dragging with altkey click, so I write code like below.

```
$("#object").draggable({ 
        drag: function( event, ui ) { 
                if (event.shiftKey) { 
                    ui.helper.draggable('option', 'axis', "x");
                } else if (event.altKey) { 
                    ui.helper.draggable('option', 'axis', "y"); 
                } else {
                    ui.helper.draggable('option', 'axis', false);
                }       
        }
    });
```

But it doesn't work seamlessly, that is, reverts to the initial position not starting at the last position when axis changing(x->y, vice versa).
How to write a code dragged with a smooth axis changing?
A working jsfiddle code is at http://jsfiddle.net/2x7us6gm/
Any answers will be appreciated.

Comment: add a minimal working example so that you get more help

Comment: It is starting from the last position

Comment: It starts from the last position when axis change from none to x, y or from x, y to none, but it reverts to original position when axis change from x to y, or from y to x